# What's wrong with this logical operation work?

Tags: c++, logical-operators

I'm trying to create an if statement that validates that the user's bet is either exactly 100, 300 or 500. What am i doing wrong?

```
if ((roundBet != 100) || (roundBet != 300) || (roundBet != 500))
{
    cout << "Incorrect input";
    // Call round again
    newRound();
}
```

Comment: Note that you could remove three-quarters of the parentheses from that `if` statement without changing its meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((roundBet != 100) || (roundBet != 300) || (roundBet != 500))
```

This will evaluates as `true` for all `roundBet`, because a number is either not 100(`roundBet != 100` true) or 100 (which is not 300, `roundBet != 300` true)

What you need is:

```
if ((roundBet != 100) && (roundBet != 300) && (roundBet != 500))
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the alternatives will always be true, since if `roundBet` is, say, `100`, then it will be different from `300` and `500`.

Use a logical AND `&&`